# MASM code with loops not working as expected,

Tags: loops, assembly, masm, irvine32

I am currently in the process of learning MASM, and I've faced the following task:

> Write a program that will calculate the value of f(n) according to the following recursive formula: f(n) = f(n-1) + 2*f(n-2) -2, f(0) = 0, f(1) = 3

I'm calculating for `n = 15` and since I know `f(0)`, `f(1)` I subtract two from `n`'s value.

```
TITLE Recursion Solver

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
n   SDWORD 15       ;
n2  SDWORD 0        ; n-2 (n0)
n1  SDWORD 3        ; n-1 (n1)

.code
main PROC

mov ecx, n      ; initialize loop counter
sub ecx, 2      ; 


again:
    mov eax, n1     ; eax = f(n-1)
    mov ebx, n2     ; ebx = f(n-2)
    add ebx, ebx    ; ebx = 2*f(n-2)
    sub ebx, 2      ; ebx = 2*f(n-2) - 2
    add eax, ebx    ; eax = f(n-1) + 2*f(n-2) -2
    mov ebx, n2     ;
    mov n2, eax     ;
    mov n1, ebx     ;
    loop again

    call WriteInt
    exit

main ENDP

END main
```

[I wrote a simple C++ program to calculate the `n`'th value according to the formula](https://ideone.com/iMCa76), but for some reason the assembly program isn't working as expected.

Here's the output of my C++ program:

```
f(0) = 0
f(1) = 3
f(2) = 1
f(3) = 5
f(4) = 5
f(5) = 13
f(6) = 21
f(7) = 45
f(8) = 85
f(9) = 173
f(10) = 341
f(11) = 685
f(12) = 1365
f(13) = 2733
f(14) = 5461
f(15) = 10925
```

and this is the integer the assembly outputs: `-13859`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one error that I can see. You mix `f(n-1)` and `f(n-2)`.
The easiest way to fix it is by changing the definition of starting point:

```
n1 SDWORD 3; n0
n2 SDWORD 0; n1
```

But of course you can swap all references to these variables in your code.

And the second error that I found:

```
mov ebx, n1     ;
mov n1, eax     ;
mov n2, ebx     ;
```

Comment: You are right (and I fixed that), but take a look at the value of f(15) in the C++ program I wrote (it's 10925 if I'm not mistaken), the assembly outputs a different (negative) number.

Comment: I don't have masm compiler, and I haven't been using assembler for very long time :). But write in your post all values (f2)...f(15) and I would try to help. Another possible problem could be with printing integers, are you sure that your WriteInt method is bug-free? :)

Comment: It's a library (irvine32) function which I guess Is bug free since our professor told us to use it :-)

Comment: I'm more interested in output from your code in MASM than the one in C :)

Comment: I've edited the code a little and added the MASM output

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49319/discussion-between-gawi-and-quaker)